# Shapes not appearing on html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a game on an html canvas, however nothing is appearing on the canvas. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. This is the code where I attempt to draw the shapes and start the game:

```
function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(50, 10, "grey", 240, 20);
    myAponent = new component(50, 10, "grey", 240, 460);
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}
```

If you wish to see all of my code, it is available here: https://js.do/nioiluc/320839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You arent properly defining `ctx`, as `myGameArea.context` returns undefined.

Try this for defining:

`var ctx = myGameArea.canvas.getContext('2d');`

and make the needed adjustments. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ztnr1gqd/